# SQL Join to Get Row with Maximum Value from Right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having problem with sql join (oracle/ms sql)
I have two tables

### A

ID | B_ID 
---|------
1  |  1
1  |  4 
2  |  3
2  |  2
----------

### B

B_ID | B_VA| B_VB
-------|--------|------- 
1       |    1    |    a
2       |    2    |    b
3       |    5    |    c
4       |    2    |    d
-----------------------

From these two tables I need A.ID, B.B_ID, B.B_VA (MAX), B.B_VB (with max B.B_VA)
So result table would be like

ID      | B_ID | B_VA| B_VB
-------|--------|--------|------- 
1       |    4    |    2    |    d
2       |    3    |    5    |    c

I tried some joins without success. Can anyone help me with query to get the result I want.

Thank you

Comment: And what you've tryed?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic as described doesn't quite correspond to the data.  For instance, `b_va` is numeric, but the column in the output is a string.

Perhaps you want this.  The data in `a` to be aggregated to get the maximum `b_id` value.  Then each column to be joined to get the corresponding `b_vb` column.  That, at least, conforms to your desired output:

```
select a.id, a.b_id, b1.b_vb as b_va, b2.b_vb
from (select id, max(b_id) as b_id
      from a
      group by id
     ) a join
     b b1
     on a.id = b1.b_id join
     b b2
     on a.b_id = b2.b_id;
```

EDIT:

For the corrected data, I think this is what you want:

```
select a.id, a.b_id, max(b1.b_va) as b_va, b2.b_vb
from (select id, max(b_id) as b_id
      from a
      group by id
     ) a join
     b b1
     on a.id = b1.b_id join
     b b2
     on a.b_id = b2.b_id
group by a.id, a.b_id, b2.b_vb;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I tried your query but did not get the result I wanted. you can see my table, query and result at [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-4drSLhriW6T0dSRklLVHNfWXM/edit?pli=1)

Comment: @cissharp . . . Try setting up an example on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT X.ID, Y.B_ID, X.B_VA, Y.B_VB
  FROM (SELECT A.ID, MAX(B_VA) AS B_VA
          FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID = B.B_ID 
          GROUP BY A.ID) AS X INNER JOIN
       A AS Z ON X.ID = Z.ID INNER JOIN
       B AS Y ON Z.B_ID=Y.B_ID AND X.B_VA=Y.B_VA
```